# MiniZinc-Gurobi different results on the same problem but with different domains variable

Tags: gurobi, minizinc, flatzinc

I'm a CS student and I'm using Gurobi for a project.

I am here because I have encountered a little problem with the Gurobi solver used along with the MiniZinc driver. In particular I have noticed that Gurobi returns two different solutions on the same optimisation problem (modelled with MiniZinc) but with a different domains for all the float problem variables.  The first problem uses a domain equal to **-2^31.0 .. 2^31.0**, while the second uses a domain equal to **-3.402823e+38..3.402823e+38**.

In the first case Gurobi returns a solution equal to **1.0**, in the second case it returns **UNSATorUNBOUNDED**.

Comment: What is the difference between the two runs? Can you tell if one of them is incorrect?

Comment: @Dekker1 The solver is called with the same way on both the two instance problems. The correct result is 1.0 since the problem comes from a known benchmark-set and other solver return that value as solution. The two instance problems are available at this links: [bigger domain variables](https://pastebin.com/Bua7ZK9u)  [smaller domain variables](https://pastebin.com/TGa3eLBF)